# Datasource for Liquibase as a Servlet Listener

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts, jndi, liquibase

I'm starting to configure Liquibase in my web.xml file, but I don't understand what the datasource attribute refers to:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>liquibase.datasource</param-name>
  <param-value>java:comp/env/jdbc/default</param-value>
</context-param>
```

The documentation says it is a JNDI datasource, but I'm using Struts, not Spring, and have my connection details in different properties files (e.g. hibernate.dev.properties, hibernate.test.properties) which I load programatically depending on the current environment:

```
Configuration hibernateConfig = new Configuration();
hibernateConfig.addProperties("com/env.specific.properties");
```

To be honest, I don't have any idea of what is or how to use JNDI.

What should I write in that specific context-param value? Is there any way to do something similar to what I do with hibernate?

I am using Tomcat 6.0, in case that may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property `liquibase.datasource` refers to the JNDI name of a `DataSource` object in your webapp's JNDI directory, as [documented](http://www.liquibase.org/manual/servlet_listener) in the Liquibase manual.

Since you are not using JNDI, you cannot use the default Servlet listener `LiquibaseServletListener` provided by Liquibase. I assume you are creating JDBC resources directly, e.g. within your web application. You probably have a C3P0 `DataSource` connection pool somewhere or access to the underlying JDBC `Connection` in some way.

If this is the case, you could roll your own initializing and inject the JDBC `Connection` into [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) as follows:

```
DataSource dataSource = ... // get from Hibernate somehow
Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
JdbcConnection liquibaseConnection = new JdbcConnection(connection);
Liquibase liquibase = new Liquibase("mychangelog.xml",...,liquibaseConnection);
liquibase.update("");
```

This code snippet is not tested, but should be s.th. like that. You may add this in your own Servlet Context Initializer listener or in your app-specific code - any place where you have the Hibernate configuration at hand and can retrieve the DataSource. As a start, have a look into the sources of `liquibase.servlet.LiquibaseServletListener` how to do that.